# Android - Creating Resizable View

Tags: android, resize, drag, launcher

I am currently working on a Dashboard with movable and resizable views. The problem I have now is that I want to resize the view by touch gestures. Therefore, I thought of a Point which I add to a view on selection, which can be dragged to resize the selected view. This is similar to the resizing procedure on the Android Homescreen.

Even after a long research, I could not come up with a solution on how to overlay another view, which has its own DragListener. I could imagine putting the selected view and the point into one ViewGroup and having the Point overlay the View. Did someone have experience with this problem? Thank you in advance.

[image: Resizable View]

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try following class.

```
package mayank.com.bhaktirasamritaswami.ui.components;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import mayank.com.bhaktirasamritaswami.R;
public class ResizableLayout extends RelativeLayout implements View.OnTouchListener{
public static int top_margine;
public ResizableLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}
public ResizableLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public void init(){
    addView(inflate(getContext(), R.layout.ui_component_resizable_layout,null));
    setOnTouchListener(this);
    dragHandle = this.findViewById(R.id.drag_handle);
}

private View dragHandle;
float downRawY;
float dY;
float height;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    int action = motionEvent.getAction();
    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        downRawY = motionEvent.getRawY();
        height = this.getMeasuredHeight();
    } else {
        View parent = (View) this.getParent();
        if(downRawY<parent.getHeight() - height + 2*dragHandle.getHeight()) {
            float rawY = motionEvent.getRawY()>20*dragHandle.getHeight()?motionEvent.getRawY():20*dragHandle.getHeight();
            MarginLayoutParams p = (MarginLayoutParams) this.getLayoutParams();
            p.topMargin = (int)rawY;
            if(p.topMargin!=0)
                this.top_margine = p.topMargin;
            this.setLayoutParams(p);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent){
    onTouch(this, motionEvent);
    return false;
}
}
```

I designed this class for vertical resizing only. You need to change onTouch method to suit your case.

Comment: Too late to ask but can you add or give any idea about "ui_component_resizable_layout" ?

Answer (score 1):

Change the onTouch() in Mayank's answer as follows

```
static final int TOP = 1, RIGHT = 2, BOTTOM = 3, LEFT = 4;
int handleMargin = 10, side = 0;
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
int action = motionEvent.getAction();
if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
// detect if tap is on handles
    downRawY = motionEvent.getRawY();
    height = this.getMeasuredHeight();
} else {
// change layout margin inside switch
    switch(side){
        case: ....
    }
    View parent = (View) this.getParent();
    if(downRawY<parent.getHeight() - height + 2*dragHandle.getHeight()) {
        float rawY = motionEvent.getRawY()>20*dragHandle.getHeight()?motionEvent.getRawY():20*dragHandle.getHeight();
        MarginLayoutParams p = (MarginLayoutParams) this.getLayoutParams();
        p.topMargin = (int)rawY;
        if(p.topMargin!=0)
            this.top_margine = p.topMargin;
        this.setLayoutParams(p);
    }
}
return false;
}
```