# How to set the width of an RecyclerView item trough touching it's frame?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I build a RecyclerView with sizable items, but at moment the width is only scalable trough a EditText input.
Is it possible to add an ScaleGestureDetector on the Frame of the items, so when user touches it a long time (500ms) he can move the frame of the item and size the width?

Could you maybe show me an example about that, I never worked with gestures.

[See this Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVB0O.png)

Comment: Check [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale) or  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35433921/android-creating-resizable-view),  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790503/can-we-use-scale-gesture-detector-for-pinch-zoom-in-android), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42142938/how-to-resize-view-with-pull-the-edge-gesture) SO posts

Comment: Wow I will check this thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, but none of these are referring to my question, at least not in detail.

Comment: @Rajen Raiyarela the questions you made a reference to, are off topic and just one of them (the most off topic one) has a accepted answer.